# How to send int array to Java code from C

Tags: android, java-native-interface

On Android platform in my native code I have allocated an int array

```
mBuffer = new int[BUFSIZE];
```

I want to send this to Java side, Java method is this

```
public void WriteBuffer(int[] buffer, int size) 
{

}
```

I call back to java code like this

```
const char* callback = "WriteBuffer";

mWriteMethod =  env->GetMethodID(cls, callback, "([II)V");
```

This calls the java method its just that in my Java code the buffer is null. As I am really passing a pointer to memory that was dynamically allocated rather than an actual array is probably why it doesn't work but I don't know how to pass a pointer to Java. 
I need the buffer parameter as an integer array on the Java side anyway.

Anyone know how I can modify the above to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need the 'size' parameter in that callback method. The Java code can use buffer.length.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your question is you want call the java method `WriteBuffer` and pass a `int[]` to it.
Some pseudo-code which you will need in jni

```
jintArray buffer; 
buffer= (*env)->NewIntArray(env, BUFSIZE); 
(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, buffer, 0,BUFSIZE, mBuffer);
```

`SetIntArrayRegion()` will copy from mBuffer into the Java array.